# Various packages not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: curl, ipython, wget, tar, enthought

I'm new to ipython or any programming and trying to view the Illumina tutorial using Enthought Canopy. The tutorial requires downloading of data with given command:

```
!(wget ftp://ftp.microbio.me/qiime/tutorial_files/moving_pictures_tutorial-1.9.0.tgz || curl -O ftp://ftp.microbio.me/qiime/tutorial_files/moving_pictures_tutorial-1.9.0.tgz)
!tar -xzf moving_pictures_tutorial-1.9.0.tgz
```

But I received 'wget' (and 'curl') is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file, and "Function not implemented" for !tar command. Did a search online for solutions and tried to set the environment path to the executable bin:

```
c:\users\ng\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\scripts;C:\Users\Ng\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\EGG-INFO\curl\usr\bin;C:\Users\Ng\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\EGG-INFO\tar\usr\bin;C:\Users\Ng\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\EGG-INFO\wget
```

It seems to work for curl when I tried with PyLab, but the other 2 error messages remained the same. If I typed the tutorial commands in Canopy Editor after changing the environment path, there is an asterisk within [] but nothing happen. It was like the notebook stopped working: when I input 1+1 after the tutorial commands, nothing happened.

I have tried on 2 computers with the same errors.

Answer (score 2):

It's important to understand the difference between the IPython prompt (the prompt in Canopy), which is an interactive prompt that interprets Python statements, and the system command prompt (or shell), which interprets operating system commands.  (You can open a command prompt in Canopy from the "Tools" menu.)

`wget`, `tar`, and `curl` are commands for a Linux or Unix-like system (typically this is an interpreter called a bash prompt).  Typing a `!` at the start of a line on the IPython prompt (like you did in Canopy) passes those commands through to an underlying shell.  It looks like you are on a Windows machine but are trying to use bash commands, hence the error.

Probably what you want to do is try those commands using a bash shell for windows, like Git Bash (it comes with git, a version control system) and can be found [here](https://msysgit.github.io/).

Otherwise, locate a tutorial that can be downloaded a little more simply.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your help. I'm not sure I understand what you meant. As the tutorial requires ipython notebook to view, I'm trying to use Canopy. But do you mean I can't use ipython notebook on Windows? I installed Git Bash and input those commands, but I got 'event not found' back. Have no idea what's going on.

Comment: The Notebook assumes you are using Linux or Mac OS...  You could try putting the URL directly into your browser and downloading the target directly.  Then unpack the .tgz using Windows tools (Maybe double-clicking will work, or maybe you'll need to download some kind of ZIP utility).  When you launch the IPython notebook, make sure you're in the same directory as the file you unpacked and start with the second cell that says `from IPython.display import FileLinks, FileLink`